# Is it possible to list the allowedValues of a SimpleSchema schema in the client using meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

I am using Simple Schema to validate my database entries in a meteor application. I started developing a module to create forms automatically (I know autoform is quite good, but it was not exactly what I needed). To make the radio component I need to know the allowed values for that field, and since it was already specified in the schema I wanted to know if it is possible to retrieve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a very simple schema:

```
s=new SimpleSchema({
  list: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ["foo","bar"]
  }
});
```

If you explore the created object you'll find that:

```
s._schema['list'].allowedValues
```

returns

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

One can deduce the general pattern is:

```
schemaObject._schema['keyName'].allowedValues
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. I was trying something similar, but apparently when a schema is created the data is normalized and not all properties become available. This is what they say in the documentation:

"Call MySchema.schema([key]) to get the schema definition object. If you specify a key, then only the schema definition for that key is returned.

Note that this may not match exactly what you passed into the SimpleSchema constructor. The schema definition object is normalized internally, and this method returns the normalized copy."

Comment: Can you show the code for your schema definition then?

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer is completely correct. It was my fault, because of a typo it wasn't returning the right stuff. Thanks for the help.